# `stack build` failed due to `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` on Mac OS X using nix

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

First the error messages:

```
$ stack build
Linking /Users/yuzhao/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4 ...
clang-5.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang-5.0: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_info, _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding5_closure , _hs_iconv_open , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding14_bytes , _hs_iconv_close , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_bytes , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_closure , _hs_iconv , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_info )
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_open)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_close)
  "_locale_charset", referenced from:
      _localeEncoding in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building simple Setup.hs using:
      /Users/yuzhao/.nix-profile/bin/ghc -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-2.2.0.1 /Users/yuzhao/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs /Users/yuzhao/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -o /Users/yuzhao/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.4
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I am using `nix` and I've found many other solutions to this error messages using `Homebrew`, not `nix`.

Also, according to [stack docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#use-stack-as-normal), `stack setup` give me the same error messages.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359289/architecture-x86-64-while-running-haskell-code-haskell-osx-iconv

Comment: Hi, @yairchu I've tried every method this answer provides, none works for me. I also find all paths contain `libiconv` and tried one by one. It does not work, either.