# `nix-env -i stack` failed on Mac OS X

Tags: haskell-stack, nix

Because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386121/stack-build-failed-due-to-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-mac-o), and some one told me that I should install `stack` and `cabal-install` using nix, so I am now trying to install `haskell-stack` using `nix-env -i`.

Whole error messages are [here](https://pastebin.com/GAzypadz).

```
$ nix-env -i stack
...
lib/machserver.cpp:180:27: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
In file included from lib/alloc.cpp:32:
In file included from ./security_utilities/globalizer.h:31:
In file included from ./security_utilities/threading.h:40:
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:67:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
#if _HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC
    ^
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:41:29: note: expanded from macro '_HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC'
#define _HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC (defined(__ppc64__) || defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
                            ^
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:67:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:41:51: note: expanded from macro '_HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC'
#define _HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC (defined(__ppc64__) || defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
                                                  ^
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:67:5: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:41:72: note: expanded from macro '_HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC'
#define _HAVE_64BIT_ATOMIC (defined(__ppc64__) || defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
                                                                       ^
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:119:50: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        { while (!casb(store, value, store)) /* again */; return value; }
                                                        ^
./security_utilities/threading_internal.h:119:50: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
4 warnings generated.
4 warnings generated.
4 warnings generated.
5 warnings generated.
make[2]: *** [/nix/store/204lvxmsigkgkdv2c0fvkqalxmg4fik5-gnustep-make-2.7.0/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/Instance/library.make:278: internal-library-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/nix/store/204lvxmsigkgkdv2c0fvkqalxmg4fik5-gnustep-make-2.7.0/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/Master/rules.make:297: security_utilities.all.library.variables] Error 2
make: *** [/nix/store/204lvxmsigkgkdv2c0fvkqalxmg4fik5-gnustep-make-2.7.0/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/Master/library.make:37: internal-all] Error 2
builder for '/nix/store/xxja1zlr9xqvl4vij85lcf30h5s6yyi5-libsecurity_utilities-osx-10.7.5.drv' failed with exit code 2
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/g2i0xac4g4173561i5lsgn7pncswzmqd-SecurityTool-55115.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
copying path '/nix/store/b5j4s3wmh2bji4ck8wrvizh5knfnw4mw-pem-0.2.4' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/ss179ilk0x4yb6z1dks3aa9z5b0bzih5-x509-system-1.6.6.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/7f4a2s6ri62dm37md14wxla62hygxg0z-connection-0.2.8.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/lg6k2p3v4sfj6w9kb3bapizzr8qk3i3p-http-client-tls-0.3.5.3.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built

cannot build derivation '/nix/store/djqw65b0cnlpdfpadxhnqr344qrwdqa9-stack-1.9.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/djqw65b0cnlpdfpadxhnqr344qrwdqa9-stack-1.9.1.drv' failed
```

and

```
$ uname -a                                                                                             
Darwin YudeMBP.local 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Fri Oct  5 19:41:49 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4903.221.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to install stack from a Nixpkgs version with a broken dependency of `stack`.

You can see build age and links to their statuses [in HowOldIs](https://howoldis.herokuapp.com/).

To change the channel you're installing from, use the `nix-channel` command.

For example:

```
# add the config
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-18.09-darwin nixpkgs
# download the latest nix expressions
nix-channel --update
```

Comment: Hi, I am using `Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0`, should I add the same channel?

Comment: I am also getting this warning when install `stack` after channel updated: `warning: name collision in input Nix expressions, skipping '/Users/yuzhao/.nix-defexpr/channels_root/nixpkgs'`

Comment: `18.09` is the stable Nixpkgs/NixOS version which is not really related to the Darwin Kernel Version. That said, kernel and OS/X updates have caused compatibility issues in the past. If you run into compilation problems, dynamic linking problems or crashes, #nix-darwin on freenode IRC may be of help.

Comment: You can also try installing a different version of stack. You can see all past versions of it and how to install them here https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/?channel=nixpkgs-20.03-darwin&package=stack